# on delete remove values with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have two tables with foreign key relationship (1 to many). How can I do that when I'll remove item from first table, it will delete automatically all values with it's foreign key from second table?

[image]

So when I'll remove item from 1 table it will remove all items from 2 table whih NameId = ID of 1 table

Comment: I like the picture :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the database management system;  with MS SQL Server, you can set a foreign key to "ON DELETE CASCADE" which does exactly what you're asking for.

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Answer (score 0):

You could just write a function for that:

```
public void RemoveWithRelatedEntries(int table1ItemID)
{
    using(var db = new dbEntities())
    {
        // get all entities of table 2
        var tab2Entities = db.table2.Where(tab2Ent=>tab2Ent.table1Reference == table1ItemID);
        // remove all those entities
        foreach(table2Item item in tab2Entities)
        {            
            db.table2.Remove(item);
        }
        // finally remove entity from table 1
        var table1entitiy = db.table1.Find(table1ItemID);
        db.table1.Remove(table1entity);
        db.Save();
    }
}
```

there are probably more elegant solutions but this was what came first to my mind.